# How to save files when using digital ocean serverless functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, digital-ocean, serverless, slack

I am trying to host my Slack bot and web scraper in a digital ocean function. But just thinking about this problem, I need storage space to store my scrapers results. When using Digital Ocean functions is it possible to save text and CSV files or will I need to add a database or use a droplet VM? The files I need to save in total are under 1GB around 50 MB not including my code files.

I'm using functions because I want to experiment using serverless architecture and two because I think it would be a good cheap option to host my Slack bot.

Are there any better options for my goals?